# How to make a server request call from android secure like google api with sha1?

Tags: php, android

I'm making an application which always call server to load data(JSON data).
Like google api how can i secure that the POST request is from my android application or not.
How to secure that?

My code I always sent POST requst to php server is given below

The below code sent data such as phone and password to login
But if any one copy this from my android app and used in their app. then the server will hacked. how can I prevent it from **accepting POST request only from my android application and not from any other sources.**

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REQ_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "" + response , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            String message = null;
            if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                message=("Network Timeout Error");}
            else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                message=("Authentication Failure");}
            else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                message=("Server Error");}
            else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                message=("Network Error");}
            else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                message=("Network Timeout Error");}
            error.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "" + message , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
 Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("reqtype", "login");
            params.put("phone", phone);
            params.put("pass", password);
            return params;
        }
    };

    int socketTimeout = 15000;//30 seconds - change to what you want
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
    ServerRequest.getInstance(HomeActivity.this).addtoRequestQue(stringRequest);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So need to learn first SSL for android and need to create SSL certificate in server end.

**Concepts**

> In a typical SSL usage scenario, a server is configured with a
>   certificate containing a public key as well as a matching private key.
>   As part of the handshake between an SSL client and server, the server
>   proves it has the private key by signing its certificate with
>   [public-key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) cryptography.

[For more info read link](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html)

> The following example will make these concepts a little more concrete.
>   In the snippet below from a command line, the openssl tool's s_client
>   command looks at Wikipedia's server certificate information. It
>   specifies port 443 because that is the default for HTTPS. The command
>   sends the output of openssl s_client to openssl x509, which formats
>   information about certificates according to the X.509 standard.
>   Specifically, the command asks for the subject, which contains the
>   server name information, and the issuer, which identifies the CA.

```
$ openssl s_client -connect wikipedia.org:443 | openssl x509 -noout -subject -issuer
subject= /serialNumber=sOrr2rKpMVP70Z6E9BT5reY008SJEdYv/C=US/O=*.wikipedia.org/OU=GT03314600/OU=See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)11/OU=Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R)/CN=*.wikipedia.org
issuer= /C=US/O=GeoTrust, Inc./CN=RapidSSL CA
```

No you need to write code at your's end like below :-

```
public static SSLContext getSSLContextObject() {
    if (sslContext == null) {
        InputStream certificateInputStream = null;
        CertificateFactory certificateFactory = null;
        Certificate certificate = null;
        String keyStoreType = null;
        KeyStore keyStore = null;
        String trustManagerAlgorithm = null;
        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = null;
        try {
            certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

            certificateInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(FliplearnApp
                    .getInstance().getAssets().open("certificateName.any.crt"));

            try {
                certificate = certificateFactory
                        .generateCertificate(certificateInputStream);
            } finally {
                certificateInputStream.close();
            }
            // Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
            keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
            keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
            keyStore.load(null, null);
            keyStore.setCertificateEntry("certificate", certificate);
            // Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
            trustManagerAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory
                    .getDefaultAlgorithm();
            trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory
                    .getInstance(trustManagerAlgorithm);
            trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);
            // Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
            sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sslContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(),
                    null);

        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sslContext;
}
```

No you need to write your code with using SSL context object like below :-

```
public class Api {

    private SSLContext sslContext;
    private int lastResponseCode;

    public int getLastResponseCode() {
        return lastResponseCode;
    }

    public Api(AuthenticationParameters authParams) throws Exception {

        File clientCertFile = authParams.getClientCertificate();

        sslContext = getSSLContextObject();

        CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());
    }


    public String doGet(String url)  throws Exception {
        String result = null;

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL requestedUrl = new URL(url);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) requestedUrl.openConnection();
            if(urlConnection instanceof HttpsURLConnection) {
                ((HttpsURLConnection)urlConnection).setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
            }
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(1500);
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(1500);

            lastResponseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            result = IOUtil.readFully(urlConnection.getInputStream());

        } catch(Exception ex) {
            result = ex.toString();
        } finally {
            if(urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now you need to integrate above code into your volley.

Comment: But how SSL can only help in this? I need to verify that the reqest call is came from my app or not, please help me

Comment: So server generate certificate .crt and you put this certificate into your assets folder. When u calling api and u make ssl context to server.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the device type and even device id as a header param of your network call. So on the server end, you can validate if the device and the id sent in the header is android or other and hence can be accessible or not. Does this help?